publishing docfx as wiki
I have this step
  - script: |
      echo Publishing to Azure DevOps Wiki
      az extension show --name azure-devops >nul 2>&1
      if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
        az extension add --name azure-devops --allow-preview false
      ) else (
        echo Azure DevOps extension is already installed.
      )
      az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/orgarniaztion project=FXTestNameProj 
      echo Checking existing wikis
      for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('az devops wiki list --query "value[?name==''FXTestName''].name" --output tsv') do set existingWiki=%%i
      echo Existing wiki: %existingWiki%
      if "%existingWiki%"=="" (
        echo Creating a new wiki
        az devops wiki create --name FXTestName --type project --version master --path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\docfx-site
        echo Wiki creation successful
      ) else (
        echo Updating existing wiki
        az devops wiki update --name FXTestName --path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\docfx-site
        echo Wiki update successful
      )
      echo Wiki publishing complete
    displayName: Publish Documentation to Wiki
    env:
      AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)

but it writes out
Publishing to Azure DevOps Wiki
Finishing: Publish Documentation to Wiki
and the wiki in devops is still not shown
is there a way to debug it more? are there any other logs?
EDIT: I tried to change some permissions and still nothing

Hi @kolek, what's the latest state of the issue? Have you checked below answer? Let me know if you have any question.

It seems there are several errors in your commands.

az devops wiki create --name FXTestName --type project --version master --path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\docfx-site


The accepted values of --type are codewiki and projectwiki. project isn't an accepted value.
There isn't a parameter named --path. It uses --mapped-path to map path of the new wiki and is required for codewiki type.


az devops wiki update --name FXTestName --path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\docfx-site


There isn't such command az devops wiki update.
You can update a specific page instead of the whole wiki using az devops wiki page update.

Whether it is a codewiki or projectwiki, it is a git repo. It is recommended that you use git commands to manage your wiki and perform version control. You can access projectwiki repo from https://dev.azure.com/<Org_Name>/<Team_Project_Name>/_git/<Wiki_Name>. See more info from How can I go to the Git repository?.
